# Log messages disappear from GAE dev server when running a backend instance

Tags: google-app-engine

I am developing a web application on an App Engine backend using the GAE dev server. My problem is that as soon as I start serving pages from the backend, log messages stop appearing on the log console. Not all logging goes away. The start up log entries look normal.  I even see that annoying "can't open zipfile" message with tags that show that the message was logged from the backend instance. It's only logging calls executed when my pages are served by the backend instance that don't appear.

I don't know if this is a bug or if I should be looking some other place for my logs. If I upload the app to the production server and look in the logs, the messages are present.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be a bug. Do you have a small sample app that reproduces this?

Answer (score 1):

Backends has separate logs just like different application versions has. Select your backend in a drop-down menu, in the blue bar at the top of the appengine admin console and you will see logs from the backend.

Comment: As I said in my question, I can see log entries from backend instances just fine using the dashboard on appengine.google.com. What I cannot see are the log entries on my local machine. There is no log viewer for the SDK console. Instead, there is a log console. I would expect to see the log messages appear on the log console, but they don't. So I am wondering if log messages from backend instances are logged somewhere else or is this a bug?